# Enter the number of students – Enter the name, age, height of each student. Print list in sorted order Name(Abc)>Age(small-large)>Height (small-large)

Tags: python, sorting

This is my code i don't know what i'm doing wrong. TypeError: 'Students' object is not subscriptable
this is the error of this code and i don't know how to fix it i try many ways

```
import operator
from operator import itemgetter, attrgetter
class Students:
    def __init__(self,name,age,height):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.height = height

def input_student_info():
    name = input("Enter student name: " )
    age = input("Enter student age: " )
    height = input("Enter student height: " )
    student = Students(name,age,height)
    return student

def print_student_info(student):
    print("Student name: " + student.name)
    print("Student age: " + student.age)
    print("Student height: " + student.height)

def input_students_info():
    std = []
    total_students = int(input("How many student: "))
    for i in range(total_students):
        print("Student " + str(i+1) + ": " )
        stu = input_student_info()
        std.append(stu)     
    return std

def print_students_info(std):
    for i in range(len(std)):
        print("Student " + str(i+1) + ": " )
        print_student_info(std[i])

def sort_list(std):
    std.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0))    
        

def main():
    students = input_students_info()
    input("Press Enter to continue")
    students_new = sort_list(students)
    print_students_info(students_new)

main()
```

please fix the thing i doing wrong and explain what i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `sort_list`, you are using `operator.itemgetter(0)`.

If you have a `Students` object like so:

```py
s = Students(...)
```

Then `operator.itemgetter(0)` is performing something analogous to:

```py
s[0]
```

There is no value in a `Students` object that can be accessed with square brackets, which is why you're getting the error `'Students' object is not subscriptable`.

Instead, you should be sorting with the `attrgetter()` method, which accesses a named attribute of the objects.

```py
stu.sort(key=operator.attrgetter("age"))
```